# $this->Auth->login() creates correct query that returns 1 row, but fails IF check (server specific issue)

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.2

We have a site that we're moving to a new server.  Everything worked fine on the old server.  It's just the start of a site, so it's pretty bare-bones.

When moving to our new server, trying to log-in no longer works.  BUT - according to debugKit, the query generated by `$this->Auth->login()`:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` 
FROM `shopping_main`.`users` AS `User` 
WHERE `User`.`username` = 'another' 
AND `User`.`password` = '3813dd3a5eeb39c857d56f9ae58ec7f8237e5eb3' 
LIMIT 1
```

IS returning 1 row - yet this if block fails:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are now logged in.'));
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
}
```

PDO is installed on both (same version) - not sure if that matters, but we've had weird issues before w/ that.

When doing a fresh install of CakePHP 2.2 stable, everything lights up green (database connection, modrewrite...etc etc.)

I would have thought there was something wrong with our data, or code...etc, but - it's the same data, the same code, and that's verified by the fact that it DOES return 1 row.

Below is my most recent `$components` array in the AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Cookie',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'admin'=>true),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin'=>true)
    )
);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

According to our server guy, the server we're having the issue on is the only one with PECL intalled - when he removed it, the login worked.  (We need it on the server for other things - why/what would cause that to keep our login from working?)

Comment: tried clearing the cake cache?

Comment: Ross - yep, cleared all cake cache.

Comment: It might be possible that your session isn't writing. If it's not able to write the session, `AuthComponent::login()` will fail despite the user existing in the database.

Comment: @jeremyharris: Sessions are writing just fine (tested and verified)

Comment: @Dave Are you using any behaviors on the user model that might be modifying the results? Also, throw `debug($result);` statement right after the result is found in `lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent::identify()` to see the results it gets from authenticating and let us know.

Comment: debug returns false - no behaviors

Comment: Very stranger! I think you should use debug ();die; inside cakephp core libs, until you find the exactly line, that make $this->Auth->login return false.

Comment: Are you using Form based Auth?

Comment: @Arun Jain - I'm using a form to enter username/password.

Comment: @Guilherme Torres Castro - good idea.

Comment: Updated code mentioning PECL issue causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer by Original Poster (me):**

According to our server guy, "There are two ways to load PDO. The first is by using easyapache to install the PDO php extension. The second is by installing the PDO via PECL. It appears that the modules in question are different."

Apparently, this server had PECL on it instead of the normal easyapache PDO.  When he removed that, and restarted/reset it with the easyapache PDO, everything worked great.

So - sounds like CakePHP requires the "normal" PDO.

Mystery solved.

---

If you have PECL instead, you can use this workaround:

1. Create a file "HpMysql.php" in your Datasource folder and add this code/class: https://github.com/lorenzo/HipHop/blob/master/Model/Datasource/Database/HpMysql.php
2. Change your database.php 'datasource' to 'HpMysql'

Comment: Wow, how odd! Glad you figured it out :)