# Cakephp Auth login returns false even though SQL query finds rows

Tags: mysql, cakephp, authentication, pdo, components

I have Cakephp app installed on a linux box.
The Mysql Driver is installed and php-pecl-acl has been removed.
There are no problems with the Cookies. The users and passwords exist in the database. The password is a CHAR(40) in the database.

The Auth->login() method **always returns false**, even though the sql query debug log shows that rows affected = 1

```
array(
'log' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'query' => 'SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, FROM `somedatabase`.`users` AS `User`   WHERE `User`.`username` = 'someuser' AND `User`.`password` = '2d7a34c9ef8efa2cfdf4b89175f7edec1cd0ddda'    LIMIT 1',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 2
    )
),
'count' => (int) 1,
'time' => (float) 2
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the exact same issue I was having that ended up being a server-specific issue related to PDO / PECL:

[$this->Auth->login() creates correct query that returns 1 row, but fails IF check (server specific issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421213/this-auth-login-creates-correct-query-that-returns-1-row-but-fails-if-chec)

---

**Edit:**
Comment from OP about how he fixed:

> I uninstalled PECL, then uninstalled php-pdo and put back the original
>   php.ini file. After that I reinstalled mysql-php and php-pdo packages
>   from Amazon and it worked. You were correct it was server issue with
>   the pdo installation.

Comment: Dave, I've removed PECL, with a yum remove php-pecl-apc. The login still fails.

Comment: @Alex - it sounds like you did not thoroughly read the answer.

Comment: Im pretty sure I did not install the drivers with PECL but I will try again using easyapache.  The command I used was: sudo yum install -y php-devel php-mysql php-pdo

Comment: @Chris. I uninstalled PECL, then uninstalled php-pdo and put back the original php.ini file. After that I reinstalled mysql-php and php-pdo packages from Amazon and it worked. You were correct it was server issue with the pdo installation. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure who Chris is but glad to help - or at least pass along information that other people shared with me :)

Answer (score 0):

I to had the same problem. I had contacted my server man he said that we didn't installed either PECL or php-pdo packages. What would be the problem.