# Cakephp - array indexes show numbers instead of the Model name

Tags: php, cakephp

I've got cake applications that work ok on my home server, and also worked ok on the production server. However since the host provider changed the php version 5.3.13 to 5.3.21, things have come askew. 
The main failing is that the array indexes show numbers instead of the Model name (in this case Article).
For example:

> array(
>       (int) 0 => array(
>           'id' => '12',
>           'title_eng' => 'News Snippets Spain: 19 February',

instead of

> array(
>       'Article' => array(
>           'id' => '12',
>           'title_eng' => 'News Snippets Spain: 19 February',

I have got the host provider to reinstall pdo_mysql.so  but that hasn't helped.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Various versions 2+  so the new php should not be an issue I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is, this is similar to the [issue I was having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421213/this-auth-login-creates-correct-query-that-returns-1-row-but-fails-if-chec/11525014#11525014).

**Answer:**

> According to our server guy, "There are two ways to load PDO. The
>   first is by using easyapache to install the PDO php extension. The
>   second is by installing the PDO via PECL. It appears that the modules
>   in question are different."
>
> Apparently, this server had PECL on it instead of the normal
>   easyapache PDO. When he removed that, and restarted/reset it with the
>   easyapache PDO, everything worked great.
>
> So - sounds like CakePHP requires the "normal" PDO.
>
> Mystery solved.

(I posted it here instead of calling it a duplicate, since it's not really a duplicate question - I just think it has the same answer)

Comment: thanks for the feedback - I'll see if my hosting supplier can do something based on this.

Comment: Glad to hear!  I feel your pain - this issue had me banging my head against the wall for quite awhile.

Comment: Once again thanks for sharing the solution with us, this could have taken literally weeks to resolve.

Comment: @Dave i have the same problem and i am not sure if i understand your answer correctly.. can you explain a bit more? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526140/cakephp-retrieving-data-from-model-using-find-array-keys-doesnt-display-corre

Comment: @fnkbz - not sure what else could be clarified.  What don't you understand?