# CakePHP retrieving data from model using find(), array keys doesnt display correctly

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am using find to retrieve data from the database like this:

```
         $test = $this->VevD01VevDateYears->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('VevD01VevDateYears.D01_Vev_Type' => 1)
        ));
```

The expected array was suppose to be like this:

```
Array
(
[VevD01VevDateYears] => Array
    (
        [D01_Vev_Type] => 1
        [D01_Vev_Years] => 2014
        [D01_Vev_Date_Pub] => 2014-12-05 00:00:00
    )

)
```

Instead of the above array i get this weird one:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [VevD01VevDateYears__D01_Vev_Ty] => 1
        [VevD01VevDateYears__D01_Vev_Ye] => 2014
        [VevD01VevDateYears__D01_Vev_Da] => 2014-12-05 00:00:00
    )

)
```

I dont find anything wrong with the query and it returns the correct array when i retrieve data from other tables without messing with the keys. What is going wrong with this one?

Comment: I might not be 100% sure on this but try adding "public $recursive = -1;" to your AppModel

Comment: @IWillScoop I added it to my AppModel but no luck. I'm still getting the wrong array.Any ideas?

Comment: Try using "$singleEntry = array_pop($test);" to get the single entry since you're just using find->first.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue in the past.

The problem I noticed was coming from the Config settings in my app.

In `Cake->Config->Core.php`

When debug > 0, you will get results with keys in the form of
`array{Model__field}`

But when debug = 0, it shows as
`array{Model} => field`