# Logs in correctly in localhost but fails on live server

Tags: php, cakephp

The login code is like below:

```
if ($this->request->is ( 'post' )) {
    if ($this->Auth->login ()) {
                    ..
    }
}
```

This one works correctly in my localhost. But when I hosted this code in a server, it doesn't allow me to login. I also try to do `debug($this->Auth->login())` which returns true on localhost but on live server it returns false. Is there any possible reason for this?

I checked db connection. I'm able to execute queries. Everything works well on my local machine, but on live server, it doesn't login.

Comment: Take a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421213/this-auth-login-creates-correct-query-that-returns-1-row-but-fails-if-chec

Comment: Thanks for the post, I just checked the version of my PHP server, it was running in 5.2, I changed it with 5.5. It's working fine now.